# Python Create new column and perform operation with it as well as other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe,

```
x   y   z   new_col
1   2   3    1
1   2   3    4
1   2   3    7
1   2   3    10
1   2   3    13
```

Want to create a new column and set a value 1 to first row.
And all other value for new column will be 1+3(3 from z), then 4+3 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

You can perform a shifted cumulative sum:

```
df['new'] = 1 + df['z'].shift().fillna(0).astype(int).cumsum()

print(df)

   x  y  z  new
0  1  2  3    1
1  1  2  3    4
2  1  2  3    7
3  1  2  3   10
4  1  2  3   13
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp, and what if istead of cumsum I had to multiply it with column z,
1 * 3, 3 * 3, 9*3 and so on. 
Note: z column can be any value

Comment: @BarsmansvapsFriends, That would be [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), where you should show what you've tried :).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
df.assign(new_col = lambda x: 1 + x['z'].shift().cumsum()).fillna(1).astype(int)
    x   y   z   new_col
0   1   2   3   1
1   1   2   3   4
2   1   2   3   7
3   1   2   3   10
4   1   2   3   13
```

if you want more specific control over type cast and na filling you can also use the more verbose:

```
df.assign(new_col = lambda x: 1 + x['z'].shift().cumsum()
          ).fillna({'new_col':1}).astype({'new_col': int})
```

Actually, you can use the same logic as from jpp's answer but wrap it in an assign call:

```
df.assign(new_col = lambda x: 1+ x['z'].shift().fillna(0).astype(int).cumsum())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function: [pd.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

If your DataFrame is called df:

```
df['new_column'] =  df.cumsum() - df.z[0] + 1
```

The -2 is there so that your sum start to 1 as you requested

Comment: this will not generalize well if z's first value is not 3

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do it, but you have two very simple ones here:

```
df['new_col'] = (3*df.x).cumsum() - 2
df['new_col'] = 3*df.index + 1
```

The former assumes that your 'x' column only contains value 1 (if not, you can easily create a column like this `df['temp'] = 1`).

And the latter assumes that your index has no holes (which can be due to drops for instance). This two methods are easy to implement and very fast (way faster than shift cumsums for instance).

Moreover if the step you need depends on the values contained in the column `z` it can easily be adapted:

```
df['new_col'] = (df.z*df.x).cumsum() - 2

    x   y   z   new_col
0   1   2   3   1
1   1   2   3   4
2   1   2   3   7
3   1   2   3   10
4   1   2   3   13
```

Comment: sure these methods are faster than `.cumsum()` but they're also __much__ less flexible. What if on the 6th row, the value in column z is 4?